# Best way to avoid a semi-colon with an expression

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario:

```
updates['errmsg'] = data.errmsg;
((!data.question) ? (this.unset('question')) : updates['question'] = data.question)
updates['run_time'] = data.run_time
```

I'm trying to avoid the semi-colon on the first line, however, when I do omit it, the line below joins the previous line and I get an error because `data.errmsg is not a function`. How can I use an expression on the 2nd line, and not have the semi-colon on the first?

Comment: The question is WHY? What is the point of abusing side effects and suffering the consequences?

Comment: So you've chosen to lie down on a bed of nails, and now you are wondering what those little pricks on your back are?

Comment: I might be thick but it took me an age to read your code.  Think it would be clearer without the shorthand tbh.

Comment: This is one of those rare times that I honestly feel that asking why is the proper answer to this questioin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just skip the parenthesis

```
!data.question ? this.unset('question') : (updates['question'] = data.question)
```

Comment: you can wrap them after a `!`, or two. Example: `!!(a === 3 && x <= 5) ? ...`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to initialize all three in one statement then try

```
updates['errmsg'] = data.errmsg,
data.question = (!data.question ? this.unset('question') : updates['question']) ,
updates['run_time'] = data.run_time;
```

Comment: Given the utter uselessness of the question itself, it is impossible for any answer that takes it seriously to be useful, and not being useful is the suggested grounds for downvoting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
updates = {
     'errmsg': data.errmsg,
     'question': data.question || null,
     'run_time': data.run_time
}
```

or

```
updates = { 'errmsg':data.errmsg,'run_time':data.run_time }
if (data.question) { updates['question']=data.question }
```

Comment: You used a semicolon!~

Comment: @torazaburo no more semis